# How to get global variable from inside function JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

When I am calling function name in the below, I am getting lots of errors like undefined but the function is working prefect, but when I am trying to callback global variable from function or function name getting useless errors. What is the problem?.

```
    var quoteTex = "";

    function wms() {
      var location = document.getElementsByName("myInput")[0]
      var gwc = location.options[location.selectedIndex].value;
      var layername = location.options[location.selectedIndex].text;
      var url_geoserver = "http://localhost/geoserver/wms
        if (gwc == 2913) {
          var url = L.tileLayer.wms(url_geoserver, {
            layers: 'ap_cadal:bagfinal',
            format: 'image/png',
            version: '1.1.0',
            transparent: true,
            maxZoom: 28
          })
        } else if (gwc == 2912) {
          var url = L.tileLayer.wms(url_geoserver, {
            layers: 'ap_cadas:basw',
            format: 'image/png',
            version: '1.1.0',
            transparent: true,
            maxZoom: 28
          })
        }

        var te = JSON.stringify(url)
        var myjson_p = JSON.parse(te)
        var final = myjson_p["options"]["layers"]
        quoteText = `${final}`

        map.addLayer(url);

      }

      wms();
      console.log(quoteTex)

HTML 

<select  name="myInput" id="choice1" onchange="wmslayers(this);">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Please select </option></li>
     <!-- Pati -->
        <li><option value="2912">Baswari</option></li>
        <li><option value="2913">Bagjiwala</option></li>
</select>
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting? What output are you getting? What do you mean by "useless errors"? Which variable are you talking about?

Comment: i want to get quoteTex variable from inside function

Comment: Please add more information about your issue. it will be good if u show the errors.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at wms

Comment: the above error getting only when i am calling function name out side

Comment: based on dropdown selection means onchange event

Comment: There's no `quoteTex` reference anywhere inside the function ..? However, there is `quoteText`, but I doubt the final answer is, that you need to study how asynchronous programming is flowing.

Comment: i am following like this        var qu = "";
function wms(){
qu = "aa"
}
wms()

Comment: I would say that you expect ```url``` to be an object just before ```JSON.stringify``` but this is not always the case? what about if ```gwc``` is neither ```2912``` nor ```2193```? could you show the value of ```te``` or ```url``` just before the parsing?

Comment: "_useless errors_" ... There's no such errors, you've to resolve every error in order to get your script to be executed.

Comment: the main object is finding out 'layers' name  from url variable

Comment: i needed output like this way  quoTex = 'ap_cadal:bagfinal'  the url will get when i select from drop-down

Comment: this information "select from drop-down" is critical. It assumes that ```gwc``` can't be different from ```2912``` and ```2913```. If this is the case, you can __focus__ on a particular value of ```gwc```. __update__ your code accordingly. and look at what is ```url``` before ```JSON.stringify```. If not (```gwc``` can be say ```2911```) I suggest strongly to handle that case (which you have not so far)

Comment: can please help me in that way ,any reference material

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing it to work like the example below.

Return the desired result in the function instead of trying to set it within the function then set it = to the functions return value like below.

Good luck!

```js
var quoteTex = "";

function wms() {
  return text = "test";
}

console.log("1. " + quoteTex);
quoteTex = wms();
console.log("2. " + quoteTex);
```